# Precise Definition of Infinite Limits at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I bumped into some exercise I wasn't sure I'm doing correctly. it goes like this:

"prove by the Precise Definition of Infinite Limits that $\lim_{n\to \infty}-\sqrt{n} = -\infty$"

So this is what I did:

1. let's check when $a_n \lt M$, M<0 and $M\in\Re$
2. $a_n=-\sqrt{n} \lt M => \sqrt{n} \gt -M => n>M^2$
3. We can choose N as $M^2$ and it fulfills the condition because we found an N that exist that for every n>N => $a_n\lt M$

this is what I did, but I think something is missing. because I found this N but I didn't show that it does satisfy the condition.

I would appreciate your advises for this formal proof.

Comment: All is correct.  You have give a number $M<0$, no matter how large in absolute value, such than $-\sqrt{n}<M$ whenever $n>N=M^2$.  Why do you think your development is flawed?

Comment: i agree. It's right.................

Comment: unsure about the formal representation of the proof...